# Spectogram time axis is incorrect or implement smart cropping?

Tags: python, image, audio, matplotlib, plot

I am currently trying to plot the power spectrum of an audio file, but seem to have some problems with the time axis of the plot.

for instance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB8Jq.png)

This audio file has a duration of 1 second, but for some reason is the plot displaying it as having beingless than 1 second. Further more is it somehow possible to remove the grey part of the plot?..  I am currently  vertically stacking these spectogram together, and since doing it manually is tedious, I wrote a program to do it, but these grey area seem to occur in different sizes in different plots hence messing up the width of the plot..

Here is how i make the plot:

```
Y =  np.array(range(0,length/3)) * (16000.0/(512.0))
X =  np.array(range(0,entries))*(1/98.0)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,output_static_np_reshaped.T,cmap=cm.jet)
plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
plt.ylabel('Frequency(Hz)')
plt.title('Power spectrum of ' + name)
plt.colorbar()
#plt.show()
plt.savefig(spectogram_path_test+"/"+name+"_plot_static_conv.png")
plt.close()
```

Length is always 771, and entries for the plot above is 98.

And are stacking them like this:

```
 print "Saved"
    print "Saved!"
    print "Hstacked"
    images1 = Image.open(spectogram_path_test+"/"+name+"_plot_static_conv.png")
    images2 = Image.open(spectogram_path_test+"/"+name+"_plot_delta_conv.png")
    images3 = Image.open(spectogram_path_test+"/"+name+"_plot_delta_delta_conv.png")

    box = (100,55,592,496)
    cropped1  = images1.crop(box)
    cropped2  = images2.crop(box)
    cropped3  = images3.crop(box)

    width1, height1 = cropped1.size
    width2, height2 = cropped2.size
    width3, height3 = cropped3.size

    sum_width  = width1 + width2 + width3
    max_height = max(height1,height2,height3)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB',(sum_width,max_height))
    x_offset = 0

    for im in [cropped1,cropped2,cropped3]:
        new_im.paste(im,(x_offset,0))
        x_offset+=im.size[0]

    new_im.save(spectogram_path_test+"/"+name+"_plot_hstacked.png")
```

I use Matplotlib to plot the spectograms, and from PIL import Image for cropping the image, and vstacking them.

So possible solutions here:

- Either find a way to plot the spectograms such that the grey area doesn't occur
- Someway crop the image such that it is capable of automatically detect the actual size of the image (being the plot without the grey part), and vstack them..

Comment: You should provide code that can actually be executed as-is, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Then it should be easier for others to help you.